# Declare prototype and use it in same file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module-export

I have created a function that have prototypes which I will use in other files.

function.js

```
function Graph() {
  //Constructor
  this.Client = null;
}
module.exports = Graph;
Graph.prototype.Init = async function Init() {
      ....
      tokenResult = await GetToken();
};

function GetToken() {
 ...
};
```

I would use GetToken method outside of the file. so I added GetToken function as  prototype

```
function Graph() {
  //Constructor
  this.Client = null;
}
module.exports = Graph;
Graph.prototype.Init = async function Init() {
      ....
      tokenResult = await GetToken(); <== Error here
};
Graph.prototype.GetToken = function GetToken() {
     ...
};
```

When I run my program I get this error:

```
GetToken is not defined
```

Also I would know how to only export the value of the token and not the function ( so that I could use the same token )

Answer (score 1):

With function expressions like `Graph.prototype.GetToken = function GetToken()` the name `GetToken` is only local to the body of the function. So to use it the way you want to, you need to reference `this.GetToken()` to get the function from the prototype :

```js
function Graph() {
  //Constructor
  this.Client = null;
}
Graph.prototype.Init = async function Init() {
      tokenResult = await this.GetToken(); 
      console.log(tokenResult)
};
Graph.prototype.GetToken = function GetToken() {
     return Promise.resolve("GetToken Called")
};

g = new Graph()
g.Init()
```